# How does one add a key field to a named table in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I am attempting to pivot on three tables, each generated from an external data source through ODBC. Each one contains the same columns, but because they are of very variable length, simply placing the queries one below the other is impractical.

I am hesitant to use VBA, as the intended user is **not** very technically minded. I therefore was planning to use the Excel data model but to do this I need a key field, which I can't get from the data source. I therefore need a way to add a unique value to every row in each table, and to have it recognised by the Excel data model as part of the table.

### TL;DR

How does one add a unique value to every row in an Excel table, and have it recognised as part of the table by the data model?

Answer (score 1):

use `=ROW()` . no row numbers in excel is repeated right? : )